i have a question about lightning auto fill extension for chrome
i need to fill the date field with my given day month and year values as soon as a form loads from url, the form provides a calender to select the desired date of birth.
actually i want to book an appointment which has the same  page as following
link has
https://service2.diplo.de/rktermin/extern/appointment_showForm.do?locationCode=duba&realmId=1067&categoryId=3028
if someone is booking germany study visa appointments from dubai and help me in putting the date of birth with right autofill syntax i shall be very thankful.
i tried booking an appointment with autofill extension,whole page is filled with extension absolutely perfect except date of birth which i am not gettingp the right autofill code.
The rest of autofill codes are below
appointment_newAppointmentForm_lastname
appointment_newAppointmentForm_firstname
appointment_newAppointmentForm_email
appointment_newAppointmentForm_emailrepeat
appointment_newAppointmentForm_fields_0__content
appointment_newAppointmentForm_fields_1__content
appointment_newAppointmentForm_fields_2__content

Take a look to their site: https://www.tohodo.com/autofill/ You may find the help you need there.

I can't find any help for this particular problem.

General rule of thumb is: if you can do it from the Console (F12 / Console tab), you should be able to do it using Lightning Autofill. Try asking https://poe.com/LightningAutofillPro as well.
